# How to make join/leave messages in discord.py

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

```python3
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    fmt = "{} has joined"
    await bot.send_message(member, fmt.format(member, member.server))

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    fmt = '{} has left'
    await bot.send_message(member, fmt.format(member, member.server))
```

This is my code and i want to make join and leave messages without putting

```
channel = member.server.get_channel("CHANNEL_ID")
```

This code so that all servers using this bot can use join/leave messages.
If i put this code, i can use join and leave messages only for a specific server.

Comment: How do you want to determine which channel to send the message to?

Answer (score 0):

A discord channel id is exclusively for one single channel and you cant have the same id on multiple channels/servers.
You can try using a single name for the welcoming channels:

```py
channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id=modlog)
```

Or use a data bank where every server can save their own channel ids for the welcoming channel, which you can use like this:

```py
channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id=modlog)
```